# Why different ways to resolve conflicts cause to different conflicts?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-commit, git-rebase, git-pull

I would like to find an answer to why **git behaves differently** when I try to merge my local changes with those of master, **depending on the commands and sequence used**.

To ensure that I start from a clean environment, I reset everything to the latest local commit `69cf18c...` and then I cherry-pick my own changes (just one file) stored already in a Gerrit server:

```
git reset --hard 69cf18c...
git fetch ssh://...  && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

From here I have tried 3 ways to solve it and only the third one works well:

**Option 1: Pull with rebase**

```
git pull --rebase
```

Git will show me **hundreds** of changes that have nothing to do with the file I cherry-picked. Even if I try `git rebase --skip` another mysterious conflict will come, again and again, indefinitely. **Why is this happening?** Is my local history *polluted* with some older local commits that distort the rebase?

**Option 2: Pull without rebase**

```
git pull
```

Git will show me only one conflict, the one which has to do with my file, up to here everything ok. However after solving the conflict and running `git add -u && git commit`, git creates a new commit on top of mine which I cannot merge together with mine running `git rebase --interactive HEAD~2` (then I would *pick* and *squash* respectively):

```
git log
commit f65738375
Merge: 6c4e66a f235f75
       ...
commit 6c4e66a88
       ...
```

Git does not list it in the editor the commit "Merge", but instead hundreds of other commits. **Why cannot I merge the conflict into my commit?**

**Option 3: Reset, pull and then cherry-pick**

If I cherry-pick after pulling, everything works fine:

```
git reset --hard 69cf18c...
git pull
git fetch ssh://...  && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
# solve the conflict
git add -u && git commit -c FETCH_HEAD
```

**Why in this order everything works smoothly?**

Is there an explanation for these 3 options? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rebasing and cherry-picking applies one commit at a time, and you need to resolve any merge conflicts, one commit at a time. A merge merges a branch, and you only need to resolve the final merge conflict. For instance, if you on two branches changes the same line, and then on one of the branches undo the change on that branch, a cherry-pick/rebase will give you a merge conflict, a merge won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need understand difference between "git rebase" and "git merge".

"git pull --rebase" is same as "git fetch origin;git rebase"

"git pull" is same as "git fetch origin;git merge"

Git rebase moves all your local commits up to top of remote branch (by default is master branch of the remote). If multiple commits on remote branch have conflict with your local commits, you have to resolve one by one, not once, just like you climb up stairs. Finally after rebase, you'll find your local commits are on top of remote commits, and all your local commit id are changed.

Git merge just connect your local branch and remote branch with one additional merge commit without changing either commit on local or remote branch. It asks for  conflict merge once, such conflict resolving information is saved in the new created merge commit.

Git rebase is better for resolving local changes before commit. Git merge is better for merge remote branches on server, or git pull request, which won't change commit id there. Gerrit doesn't use pull request as github or bitbucket. The best practice for Gerrit is to avoid "git merge" or "git pull" locally.

It looks you hadn't rebase your local branch for a long time so there are many commits on remote branch conflicts with yours. So direct rebase is frustrated as option 1.

You can do this to resolve conflict.

1. Create another branch based on your current local branch

```
git branch -b WIP
```

2. Delete local curent (like master) branch and recreate it based on remote master branch again

```
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master origin/master
```

3. Cherry-pick you commits on local branch to master branch one by one (if there're not too many)

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick xxx (xxx is local commit on WIP branch)
...
git cherry-pick xxx
```

4. Cherry-pick gerrit commit

```
git fetch ssh://...  && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

In this way, you do not have any "git merge" operation, and save time to avoid rebase for mutliple conflicts.

Comment: That distinction makes complete sense to me, except for one point: if my local history conflicts with master, why just resetting my last commit and then rebasing does not generate the same conflicts?

Comment: To clarify more my concern: if the problem was in my local history conflicting with master, resetting only my changes would still ask me to solve all those unrelated changes when running git pull --rebase. I just retested it and does not show up any of those unrelated changes, just my own one. Also, master should be consistent with its own history: why would any of the old commits stored in my local history (just downloaded, never touched by me) not patch correctly with any recent changes? History of master is always consistent. Thanks!

Comment: If so, that should be onething happens: Someone rebased his/her commits (or even rebase another branch with different base) and force push that into remote master branch. After doing this, even you didn't change anything locally, your local base is mismatched with remote. This is what I said that, do not use rebase for remote branches and force push that. That creates a lot of problems for all team members who are frustrated to get rebase problems as you got.

Comment: For a big team, never rebase branch on server and force push that (in another word, never change base on remote branch but add more and more commits on top of it.) You can contact with owner of the branch on remote server to see whether such rebase happened there. Usually such remote branch should be protected from force push.

Comment: Such force push should be forbidden by admin, not your fault and you cannot avoid such problem.

Comment: To express more exactly, one example of force push will get the problem for you if you downloaded the code before the push: "git checkout another_branch (not master); git push -f origin HEAD:master". The last "git push -f" usually should be failed if the remote master branch is protected from force push. This operation actually set "anther branch" as the new master branch. Then you get a lot of conflict with your local (old) master branch and remote (new) master branch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the history of `FETCH_HEAD` is very different from the history of `69cf18c`

Have a look at the compared history of `FETCH_HEAD` and `69cf18c`, using a viewer (gitk, gitg, git-kraken, git-extensions ...) or by running :

```
git log --graph --oneline 69cf18c FETCH_HEAD
```

You should see that the history of both commits diverged, and that each branch has many commits (you said "hundreds") that the other branch doesn't have.

---

Option 1 is the normal behavior when your local branch has hundreds of commits to replay on top of the remote branch

Option 2 is the normal behavior of `git rebase -i` when it handles a merge commit : if the merge commit does not introduce new changes or gets "discarded"

From what you describe : Option 3 is the closest to what you are looking for.